# Selectively convert list items in python

Tags: python

So I have a list of lists in Python, where all the items are supposed to be numbers except when the list has three items. In this case, the last item is supposed to remain a string which I convert from a string. The code is as follows:

```
special_ops = [6]
program = [ line for line in temp.split(";") ]
for i in range(len(program)):
    line = [ int(p) for p in program[i].split(",")[:2] ]
    if ( line[0] in special_ops ):
        line.append( program[i].split(",")[2] )
    program[i] = line
```

The structure of the pre-parsed string looks like this:

```
0,1;2,1;2,0;3,2;6,1,a string
```

This doesn't seem very Pythonic to me so I was hoping for a more concise version of this code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's exactly your question? Please take a look here: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your code is 'ok' and you want some advices, you should ask at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think the real problem is storing data in a non-standard format that requires a custom parser.  If you want to store data in a structured format, you're better off storing it using `json`, or `pickle`, or even saving out the data to a standardized format like `.csv` that is easily parsed by existing libraries.

Comment: There are definitely several things you could do to make this more concise. Here's an obvious one: `[ line for line in temp.split(';') ]` is **exactly equivalent** to `temp.split(';')`. Why create a new list via a comprehension when you are not transforming any of the members?

Comment: @BrendanAbel I wanted to avoid having to write to a file as I have to create this structure many times and the I/O would become significant. Furthermore, the storage was supposed to be entirely internal and the parsing was necessary for data retrieval from remote servers.

Comment: @Woody1193 json and pickle data don't have to be written to file.  They are perfectly suitable for serializing data between servers (considering this is basically how most web pages work).

Comment: @BrendanAbel Consider me enlightened then. I will have to consider one or the other if this gets any more complicated than it already has. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = [x.split(',') for x in temp.split(';')]
>>> [[int(x) for x in lst] if len(lst)==2 else [int(lst[0]), int(lst[1]), lst[2]] for lst in a]
[[0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 2], [6, 1, 'a string']]
```

#### How it works

The first statement just splits up temp in a convenient list of lists of strings:

```
>>> a = [x.split(',') for x in temp.split(';')]
>>> a
[['0', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['2', '0'], ['3', '2'], ['6', '1', 'a string']]
```

The second command uses a ternary statement to treat the length-2 lists differently from the length-3 lists.  Just looking at the ternary part:

```
>>> lst = ['0', '1']
>>> [int(x) for x in lst] if len(lst)==2 else [int(lst[0]), int(lst[1]), lst[2]]
[0, 1]

>>> lst = [6, 1, 'a string']
>>> [int(x) for x in lst] if len(lst)==2 else [int(lst[0]), int(lst[1]), lst[2]]
[6, 1, 'a string']
```

#### All as one command

If one wants to avoid the intermediate variable, then the two commands above can be merged into one:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in lst] if len(lst)==2 else [int(lst[0]), int(lst[1]), lst[2]] for lst in [x.split(',') for x in temp.split(';')]]
[[0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 2], [6, 1, 'a string']]
```

Comment: I was typing this up and noticed you beat me to it.